# Parse Query Retrieving Next Object in NSNumber Stack

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, nsnumber

I'm trying to retrieve the next set of parse data from my parse class but I am totally at a stand still with how I might accomplish what I am trying to do.

Example user starts with tip #1 and then presses next and is presented with tip #2, so on and so forth.

I have a parse query on my "Next" button that should load the next tip within parse into my UILabel called tipBody and the next sequential tip number into my tipNumber label.

[image]

```
- (IBAction)nextTipAction:(id)sender
{
    [ProgressHUD show:@"Loading Next Tip"];
    //Get Current Comments//

    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Archive"];
    [query whereKey:@"body" equalTo:@"tipNumber"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {

            weakSelf.tipNumberLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tip Number: %ld", [[weakSelf.currentTip objectForKey:@"tipNumber"] integerValue]];
            [self.currentTip incrementKey:@"tipNumber" byAmount:@+1];
            [ProgressHUD dismiss];

        }
        else
        {
            [ProgressHUD dismiss];
            [ProgressHUD showError:@"Sorry! Unable to load Tips"];
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code as follow.

```
- (IBAction)nextTipAction:(id)sender
{
    NextTipNumber++;  // Assume that on didload it initiate to 1 and also load on view didload you have load first tip.

    [ProgressHUD show:@"Loading Next Tip"];
    //Get Current Comments//

    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Archive"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"tipNumber"];
    [query setLimit: NextTipNumber];   // Set the limit according which tip you want to access
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            PFObject *ArchiveObject = [objects lastObject];
            weakSelf.tipNumberLabel.text = [ArchiveObject objectForKey:@"tipNumber"];
            weakSelf.tipBody.text = [ArchiveObject objectForKey:@"body"];

            [ProgressHUD dismiss];
        }
        else
        {
            [ProgressHUD dismiss];
            [ProgressHUD showError:@"Sorry! Unable to load Tips"];
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: This is in a view controller with only two labels (tipNumberLabel and tipBody) and one button (nextButton).  When I implement your code it doesn't load the next tipNumber associated with the tipBody.

Comment: check my edited answer @JoshuaHart, did you got it or not?

Comment: is NextTipNumber++ an integer that I should be claiming in my header?

Comment: yes, and on ViewdidLoad() it will be initilize to 1

Comment: Perfect!  I had to change the numberLabel to integerValue but that's exactly what I was trying to accomplish!  Upvoted! Thank you!  :)

Comment: Happy to help...:) Happy coding!